# SharePoint Online Modern List View Item Pop-Up (DispForm) not Opening in Same Tab

Tags: sharepoint-online, list-view-web-part

I noticed some strange behavior of Modern List View After Adding on Modern Page.

If I access List View Directly then after clicking on Item Title, Item Details (DispForm) will be shown in Right Hand side Pop-Up/Blade.

[image: Modern List View with Pop-Up]

But, IF I add the Modern List View On Modern Page then its opening the item details (DispForm) pop-up in new tab.

[image: Modern List View Added on Modern Page]

[image]

Is it the Expected Behavior?? Can We force it open in same tab as same thing is working in SharePoint 2013.

**Note**: "Launch forms in a dialog?" option is "Enabled" in List Settings and No Customization done in "DispForm". List have only default Title Field. Same behavior noticed for list with multiple columns.

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It’s the default behavior.

And unfortunately, we are not able to change this behavior in SharePoint Online Modern page.

Comment: Thank you for Confirmation. I hope in future MS will improve this!!

Comment: Yeah I've been searching and longing for solution for this also and MS support told me it's the default behavior at the moment. So I cast my vote for this feature/update also, let's hope Microsoft enables the cool new side panel for the List webpart in near future (or at least to open in the same tab). :)

Comment: Any news on this? The 'open in new tab' behaviour is especially annoying if using two  listview webparts connected with the dynamic filtering feature...

Comment: Still no news or updates regarding this?